# Visual Studio Code: change the built in html5-snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the built in html(5)-snippet in Visual Studio Code?

I would like to add the script tag to the snippet for instance.

Br,
Lino

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode go to `File > Preferences > User Snippets` and then choose `HTML`. This will open the `html.json` for your own HTML snippets with an example in its comments.

For details on the syntax of this file, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets.

Comment: Can we replace the default `!` snippet?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the built-in snippet, after creating your own snippet, you need to hide the built-in snippet from IntelliSense. See: [Can I remove snippets from IntelliSense?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_can-i-remove-snippets-from-intellisense)